# How does Jetpack Compose know that a modifier affects only e.g. the drawing phase?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The Compose documentation e.g. [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/phases#phase3-drawing) mentions, that `Modifier.drawBehind` only affects the drawing phase, other phases are not re-executed when this modifier changes. But how does Jetpack Compose know that e.g. `Modifier.drawBehind` only affects the drawing phase?